# Swap icon image when hover an item block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change one  icon image with another when i hover over div with class name item with css? I tried with this: .item:hover .icon img {
  background-image:url('./images/moon.png');
} but it doesnt work. Any idea?

```
<div class="col-md-4  item">
    <span class="icon"><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="./images/sun.png"></span>
    <h3>This is text</h3>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">go</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't set a background image to an img tag.

Answer (score 1):

you would not need javascript to do so, just remove the image tag, and set the span as an icone by `background-image` property see example

```css
.item
{
background-color:#fff;
}
.item span.icon {

width:60px;
height:60px;
display:block;
background-image:url('https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/00/16/06/25576e094d32c0e.jpg');
background-size:100%;
background-color:#fff;
}
.item:hover span.icon
{
background-image:url('http://moziru.com/images/moon-clipart-evening-12.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4  item">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <h3>This is text</h3>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">go</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First my answer directly to your question:

On hover set the opacity of the  tag to 0 and then keep your new background image on the span.icon.

```
.icon { display: inline-block }
.icon:hover { background-image: url(...); }
.icon:hover .img-responsive { opacity: 0; }
```

See demo here https://codepen.io/xavortm/pen/QOBrRK

Now, if you want to refactor your code, here are a few solutions.

1. Remove the `<img>` tag and just use `background-image` to the span. Change it on hover as before
2. Keep two images with the same sizes. Toggle first/second on hover (I don't like this option)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<img>` tag with `background-image` css property . Then in `hover` property assign different opacity according to the image class in which you desire to hover.

the image that is to be shown should have high opacity (max 1) and to hide the opacity should be 0